# Is there an Eclipse equivalent for IntelliJ "go-to Declaration and usages" of a class/function?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I can right click any class or method and the "go to declaration/usages" option will open the class itself so that i can look into it with further detail. I cannot seem to find a similar solution in eclipse, only hovering over the object name will open a small window with the documentation and that's it, I cannot inspect it further or inspect the elements used inside of it. Is there a way to do it?

I have tried all the various options in the context menu and neither opens a specific class I'm hovering over

Comment: With the cursor over the class/method/attribute, press F3. For method, ctrl + hover shows a context menu to go to implementation. Take a look at the list of shortcuts, there are several useful.

Comment: Shift+hover shows the declaration as hover.

Comment: Thank you LMC, that's what I have been looking for